# C++ threads: How do I stop two different functions from being called at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to c++ threads and I'm currently using boost for threading. I am trying to figure out how to stop two functions from being called at the same time.

```
void function1(){
   //some task


}

void function2(){
   //some other task


}
 //both tasks can not run at the same time
```

how would I stop function 1 and function 2 from running at the same time?

Comment: By using a mutex?  Although you might be able to design them to be able to run them at the same time.

Comment: yea I tried using a mutex with a lock_guard. but it caused dead lock

Comment: @user3600107 Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some synchronization mechanism like a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) shared between them:

```
std::mutex m;

void function1() {
    std::lock(m);
}

void function2(){
    std::lock(m);
}
```